# Can user unbind page load event handlers, using developer tools console, before loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, security, pageload

I am wondering if there is any possibility for the user (web page user, has no access to the web page source) to unbind event handlers attached on page load.

For example:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    alert("Alert on page load");
}); 
</script>
```

By using `$('*').off();` all other events handlers except those on page load are being removed.

From what i understand, Page load events get attached and executed as and when page is rendered from the server.

Is there anyway user can defer/manipulate the page load events?

Thanks in advance